# No language definition file found with Apacite

Tags: babel, apacite

I'm using latex with `TeXmaker` as my text editor and compile there. When I hit the quick build button, an error like this occurs:

```latex
Package apacite Warning: 
No suitable language definition file (bahasa.apc) found
```

My language is Bahasa. How to solve this?

Comment: From what I can see so far this is not an error, it is a warning. The citation/bibliography package you are using (`apacite`) can adapt its output according to the document language. But for your document language the package has no definitions, so 'does not speak' your document language. I'm assuming it falls back to English. Check the citation and bibliography output to see if you are happy with it.

Comment: bahasa = Indonesian, correct? To the best of my knowledge, currently only Dutch, English, Finnish, French, German, Greek, Norwegian, Spanish and Swedish are supported directly. That said, Chapter 7 of the manual explains how you can easily create your own .apc file.